# Runtime Error 5 Sometimes in VBA Creating PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel

I have been recording/writing a macro in Excel 2016, 64 bit version. I need to create a PivotTable at the end of it. I have tried four different ways on my computer and they all work.

HOWEVER! When I send the file to another user, the PivotTable section always fails and it always returns

> Run-time Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

The other user is on a virtual desktop (Windows 2008 R2) and Office 2013, which is the 32 bit version.

I did research this issue, which is why I have so many different bits of code below, but no matter what I do, the other user gets the *Run-time Error 5*. Again, all of these work as intended on my computer, so I'm assuming there's a version issue, but I admit that I'm guessing at this point. What am I missing?

Macro recorder code:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Summary!R1C1", _
  TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Most common fix I found online:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="'Summary'!R1C1", _
  TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
```

Second most common fix I found online:

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "Table1", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("$A$1"), _
  TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6
```

I even tried to cheat by importing an existing PivotTable into a new workbook and then updating where the pivot gets its data, but I still get a *Run-time Error 5*.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
  PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Table1", Version:=6)
```

Comment: Version 6 is Excel 2016.  Maybe you should be using Version 5 for Excel 2013?

Comment: Have a look at the [PivotCaches.Create Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel) and its enumeration for `Version` [XlPivotTableVersionList Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlpivottableversionlist-enumeration-excel)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem when sharing the same code with a colleague in the UK. It worked fine at my end but she kept getting the Run-time Error 5 message.
I deleted the bit that says "**, Version:=6**" (or 8 in my case) and she reported that it ran fine!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cameron, but I am unsure how my answer "doesn't really answer the question". Nor am I asking a "different question".

The issue is **"Runtime Error 5 Sometimes in VBA Creating PivotTable"** and part of the code is "... , SourceData:= "Table1"**, Version:=6**)"

I've had a similar problem when sharing the same code with a colleague in the UK.

When I deleted the bit that says "**, Version:=6**" (or 8 in my case), she no longer got the "Runtime Error 5" notification.

Isn't that possibly what the OP was "missing"?

Comment: My mistake. Comment Removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I realized that you should used the last version of your PivotTableCache available on Excel 2013, which is 15 when you change and / or create the Pivot Cache.

Something like this:

```
Dim Wkb As Workbook, Wks As Worksheet, rDB As Range
Dim sSheet as String, sPvt as String

sSheet = "[SheetName]"
sPvt = "[PivotTableName]"

Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set Wks = Wkb.Worksheets(sSheet)
Set rDB = Wks.Range("A1:I2500")

WksI.PivotTables(sPvt).ChangePivotCache Wkb. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rDB, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) '' This is the line you need to change
'' Excel 2010 Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14
'' Excel 2013 Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am OK with
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12, not Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12