# VBA Pivot Table Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call for MS office 2016

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

Hi I am facing problem in running macro that captured the pivot table creation. I used excel 2016 to create the macros. VBA Pivot Table Run Time Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call for MS office 2016
From this line i get the error: ***invalid procedure call or argument***
**ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("page2").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _ CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="page3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _, DefaultVersion:=6**

```
Sub PIVOT()
    '
    ' PIVOT Macro
    '
    '

    Sheets("page1").Select
    Sheets.Add

   **ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("page2").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="page3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=6**
    Sheets("page3").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("fruit")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("fruit"), "Count of fruit", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("description")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Actual")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("description"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("description"). _
        CurrentPage = "group"
    Range("B15").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("page2").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="page3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=6

Comment: Edit that information into your question

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your PivotTableCache version, because if you try to run it in an earlier Excel version send this message.

Somethin like in this post:

[Runtime Error 5 Sometimes in VBA Creating PivotTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47192205/1946796)